# how do i export PDF file attachments via python

Tags: python, pdf, export, attachment

How do I extract a PDF file attachment via python? (File attached to the PDF)

I seem to not be able to find anything about this topic.

Comment: Export from what? Extract from what?

Comment: Just search google pdf python. you get many links by the way try this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyPdf/1.13

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар: thanks but that library does not include any way to extract PDF attachments... that is exactly what makes this so ugly to find... as there are a million ways to extract text

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Extract the attachment from the PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a native python solution, but try to use [pdfdetach](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=pdfdetach&ampsect=1)(1) with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
from subprocess import call
call(["pdfdetach", "-saveall", "file.pdf"])
```

(1) there is also Windows port by Cygwin